# Kotlin Update TextView after Dialog dismiss

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a dialog with a button. I want to change a TextView (txtTotalDist) in the parent fragment when the button is clicked and the dialog is closed.

I tried several methods without success:

```
rootView.btnDialogOK.setOnClickListener {
  val frag: ParentFragment()
  frag.txtTotalDist.text="A"
  //Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
  
  (activity as ParentFragment).txtTotalDist.post { txtTotalDist.text = "A" }
  //cannot be cast to ParentFragment

  txtTotalDist.post { txtTotalDist.text = "A" }
  //Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.TextView.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference

  txtTotalDist.text = "A"
  //Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

  dismiss()
}
```

I also tried to find a function in the parent fragment to override, e.g. onAttach, onResume, onStart, onViewStateRestored, but none of them start when I close the dialog. How can I do it properly?

EDIT / SOLUTION

build.gradle Module:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0'
```

Host fragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { key, bundle ->
        val result = bundle.getString("action")
        if (result=="del") refreshStatusBar()
    }
}
```

Dialog fragment:

```
rootView.btnDialogRemove.setOnClickListener {
    setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundleOf("action" to "del"))
    dismiss()
}
```

Comment: Did you try following the [instructions in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#PassingEvents)? It doesn't make sense to instantiate a new instance of the ParentFragment and do stuff with it, because that Fragment instance will never be seen or used. It doesn't make sense to cast the activity to the ParentFragment, because an Activity is not a fragment. And you can't reference properties of another class without an instance of that class.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I'll look into it.

Comment: Do you launch this dialog internally in this fragment?

Comment: I launch dialog on click on RecyclerView item (to edit the item) by val dialog = MyDialogFragment(position, adapter) and dialog.show(parentFragmentManager, "navtag")

Comment: You could implement a listener in that fragment; and pass an instance of it to the `RecyclerView`; and trigger its callback when the dialog button is clicked (its callback should have a parameter that carries the value to be set to the TextView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second fragment is nested inside in first fragment, you can pass a callback to second fragment and invoke it after closing dialog, or you can return an observable from second fragment to observe by first one.
But if your designed fragments are sibling with each other, it depends on your designed code base. If you are using fragment manager directly, you can do the same approach as above and add second fragment instead of replacing it. But if you have to replace or you are using navigation component, there is a better way to handle it like we do between two activities.
You can add below code lines to first fragment:

```
setResultListener("yourKey") { key, Any ->
        val result = anything you need to return
        //Todo something about result
    }
```

And in second activity when you want to set data after closing dialog or whenever:

```
val result = any result
setResult("yourKey",result)
```

Also you can check the below url for more information about it.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between#kotlin

Comment: It worked. Thanky you!

Comment: I don't think the callback strategy you mentioned in your first sentence will work after a screen rotation.

Comment: About callback for sibling fragments yes you are right. In this case rx observable should be a workaround. But in case of nested fragments both ways work. But I say again, using fragment manager result feature is best and has lower risk of data loss